# Assign a value to a random SKColor

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following code.

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(100))/100
}

func niceRandomColor() -> SKColor {
  println(random())
  return SKColor(hue: random(), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

This code generates a random color for me, which i assign to 3 SKNodes, which spawn randomly every second with a random color generated from "niceRandomColor()". When i check the println(random()), it shows a number between 0.00 and 0.99.

I have assigned my SKNode a name called "p1.name = random().description". I am trying to assign the SKNode name, to the colour that is randomly produced. However, for whatever reason, if the colour produces a 0.5, the name of my p1 will be 0.7 or whatever. It is not matching the colour that is produced....

Why is this? Thanks

Comment: Is using the random hue value not sufficient?

Comment: My SKNode is called var p1. I have tried to use "p1/name = random().description" but for whatever reason, the random() number that is spawned might be 0.5 but the name of p1 will be a complete different random number like 0.3. 

So my p1.name is not matching up with the actual color everytime. So I am not too sure how I can use the random Hue number..... :)

Comment: Surely that is the solution though. Your question should be "Why is the number 0.73 (or whatever) coming out as ) 0.3 when I put it into a string?

Comment: Editied. And yes, that is exactly what I am wondering :(

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `random()` you're asking for a new number.

Your `println` asks for one random number and your `SKColor` initializer asks for another one.  If you want to use a particular number for multiple purposes, save it to a variable and access the variable instead of a new call.

If you need access to the hue outside the place where you call `random()`, you can get it from the `SKColor`.  For example:

```
var clr = niceRandomColor()

var hue: CGFloat = 0.0
var saturation: CGFloat = 0.0
var brightness: CGFloat = 0.0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

if clr.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha) {
    println("\(hue)")
} else {
    println("Call failed")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip. That makes sense. I have changed my code to:

func niceRandomColor() -> SKColor {

     var color = random()
        
        return SKColor(hue: color, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

However, when I type "p1.name = color.description" there is an error because Xcode cannot identify the variable "color"....I know I need to move the var "color" elsewhere but it ruins the code if i do....

Comment: Update: the SKColor knows its hue so you can get it from there.

Comment: Thanks Phillip! I finally got it working. Cheers for your help!